# symfony2 and doctrine, encoding utf8

Tags: symfony, utf-8, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have encoding problem on my production server(first deploy on that hosting)

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset: utf8
```

but i got wrong decoded special characters  like `ó ł ę ą ć` etc
where i can check my encoding ?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my question and that is to change

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   mysqli #pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset: utf8
```

and that's it